# Why my simple code runs good on spyder but not on online IDE of SPOJ?

Tags: runtime-error, python-3.7

This is my code for the 1st beginner level question on SPOJ:
rewrite small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at the input are integers of one or two digits.
My code:

```
b=[]
while True:
    n=int(input('Enter the number less than 100 : '))
    if(n>100):
        continue
    else:
        b.append(n)
        if n==42:
           break
for i in b:
    print(i)
```

but it throws error saying:

```
Runtime error #stdin #stdout #stderr 0.15s 23320KB
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 4, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I hope I was clear, and please point out my mistakes in a kind way:) as I am a beginner and self-taught.
Thank You.

Comment: you should try with `sys.stdin` instead of `input`

Comment: I tried your suggestion! but SPOJ shows it as time limit exceeded!@Cyril Jouve

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `try` and `except` for your code.

Insert all of the code under try and then except pass

```
try:
   b = []
   while True:
       n=int(input('Enter the number less than 100 : '))
       if(n>100):
           continue
       else:
           b.append(n)
           if n==42:
              break
   for i in b:
       print(i)

except:
   pass
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the above suggestion,but SPOJ shows it as a wrong answer!

Comment: Well, the code at the last line is printing the list as many times as there are elements inside the list. The online site might be checking the answer which is being given output by sysout, which is expecting the list to be displayed only once.